# Speed is slow in SQL query with a join, maybe indexes are the problem

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm currently working on a large table (150k rows and counting), whilst it was smaller, the query I am trying was far faster, but as its grown, its very slow, even if I limit 1, it can take up to five minutes. I need to speed this up.

There are two tables, a user table (around 5000 records) and a kind of history table (around 150,000 records) which has two columns a date and status on that date.

The query is a select which finds users who **don't** have a history record on a given date.

What I'm trying to do at the moment is as follows:

```
select 
  u.user_id 
from 
  users u 
  left join history h on u.id= h.user_id and date = '20101116' 
where 
  date IS NULL;
```

How this works is I'm joining on the date `20101116` (YYYYMMDD format) and if that joined table date value is `null`, I know that I don't have a history record on that given date. This works, but it is incredibly slow, I'm wondering if there is a faster/cleverer way of doing this.

My tables are thus:

#### users

```
+------+-----------------+
|  id  |  email_address  |
+------+-----------------+
```

**history**

```
+------+-----------+--------+----------+
|  id  |  user_id  |  date  |  status  |
+------+-----------+--------+----------+
```

I only have indexes on the ID columns of both tables.

Comment: Do you have indexes created on user_id?

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the table that include the id and date?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by `where date IS NULL` ? Because the way I see it...you might get only those records without a date...in first table

Comment: @ Misnomer 'Where date is null' means I am returning only records which couldn't have a history item joined.

Comment: @Catch22 I only have indexes on the ID columns of both tables.

Comment: @Misnomer I agree, the date part of this doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @Robin-Timothy Card- that doesn't make sense though, you will want to alias that date field to help us realize what table you are coming from.  are those two different date fields ?

Comment: @Robin-Timothy Card - That is your problem, add an index to user_id.

Comment: Also add an INDEX on `u.id`, `h.user_id` and `date`.

Comment: i've added indexes on the columns above, and it is almost instant now.

Comment: Thank you all very much, could someone explain what I've just done?

Comment: @Robin-Timothy Card :-) Indexes help...helps to understand why you need them on those specific columns.

Comment: @Robin-Timothy Card- I recommend a reading on indexes in SQL http://odetocode.com/Articles/237.aspx.

Comment: @Robin-Timothy Card here is a good article by Mladen Prajdic he has a simple way of explaining indexes by using an example of a library: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/09/18/Back-To-Basics-What-is-a-Clustered-and-a-Non-Clustered.aspx

Comment: @Robin-Timothy Card - Using an index vs having no index is like looking up a page in a book using a table of contents and page numbers vs just looking through each page for the piece you want with no page #s.  you will find it eventually, but it will take a while :)

Comment: And just for the record, 150K rows is a teeny tiny table which is why we knew you needed indexes.

Answer (score 4):

> The query is a select which finds users who don't have a history record on a given date.

```
select u.user_id 
from users,  history h
where u.user_id = h.user_id 
and not exists ( select 1 
                 from history 
                 where h.user_id = u.user_id 
                 and h.date = '20101116' )
```

Comment: But it still will be slow if the correct indexes are not in place.

Comment: @HLGEM Indeed. I'd assumed the the columns were indexed which posting this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for the WHERE date is null, as you have already joined on a specific date.  To me that just doesn't make sense.  Unless you are talking about two different date fields but you haven't named them or aliased them well in your example?

There is not much in terms of optimization on such a query.  The best you could do is throw an index on user_id and possibly the date.

Comment: If I don't do WHERE date is null, I get all of the records returned. I only want records which *don't* have date values yet.

Comment: @Robin-Timothy Card - can you repost the sql by placing TableName.FieldName for both date fields.

Comment: Hi Jonm there is only one date field. I'll update with a simplified version of my table columns, hold on.

Comment: @Robin-Timothy Card - If its one date field then your query does not make sense as you are joining based on a value.  Try to add an index to user_id, and date.  Run the query and give us some feedback, I bet it runs a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
select u.user_id 
from users u 
where u.user_id not in (select h.user_id from history h where h.date = '20101116');
```

Comment: This will return the same results as the original query (it will probably even get optimized to the same query plan), but without indexes on u.user_id, h.user_id and h.date, it won't perform any faster.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your query faster, you need to add two indexes to the `history` table:

- Index on `history.user_id`
- Index on `history.date`

Try creating those, and the re-run your queries.  You should see much improved performance.